# How to place an Image in a Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, user-interface

I'm new to Swing and just need to know how to place an image on the home screen of my GUI. I don't want it to be the background. When my lecturer demoed it I think he placed it inside a JLabel. I saved the image to my laptop, but do I need to import it into the project I'm working on in Eclipse? If so, where is the best place to save it to? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Put all the images in `images` folder that you have in your project in parallel to `src` folder.

```
       F:/>Kiosk
             |
             |___src                 
                   |
                   |__main1.java
             |
             |__images
                |
                |__c.jpg
                |__d.jpg
                |__e.jpg
                |__f.jpg
```

Use this code

```
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\d.jpg"));
```

---

You can try any one

```
// Read from same package 
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("c.png"));

// Read from absolute path
ImageIO.read(new File("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\c.png"));

// Read from images folder parallel to src in your project
ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
```

---

All the above method returns `BufferedImage`.

> How to convert `BufferedImage` into `ImageIcon`?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\c.jpg"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an image subdirectory within your Eclipse project and copy the graphic to that folder. Then, extend JPanel something like this:

```
class MyImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("image/myimage.gif");
    private Image image = imageIcon.getImage();

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image != null) g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
    }
}
```

from there, you can add this panel to your main JFrame using:

```
 add(new MyImagePanel());
```